# Get all results from for loop in batch (%%a %%b %%c ... %%z)

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, registry, string-parsing

I'm trying to get the JavaHome registry key's path, and so far I have this:

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3" %%x in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\%~1" /v CurrentVersion') do set JavaTemp=%%x

for /f "skip=2 tokens=3*" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\%~1\%JavaTemp%" /v JavaHome') do set JAVA_HOME=%%a %%b
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

Note: %1 can be "JRE" or "JDK"

Reference: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0642.html

However this only gets the first two portions of the path (%%a %%b) split by whitespace. If there's more than one space in the path, this will fail to output the whole path.

I'm not too experienced with for-loops in Batch, so my question is: **how can I get all of the tokens found? (without having to do %%a %%b ... %%z)** Can I use a nested for-loop somehow?

My initial thinking was that I could just do

```
set JAVA_HOME=%%*
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "Arg1=%~1"

if not defined Arg1 (
    >&2 echo No argument passed for Arg1
    exit /b 1
)

for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%A in (
    '2^>nul reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\%Arg1%" /v CurrentVersion'
) do if /i "%%~A" == "CurrentVersion" set "JavaTemp=%%~C"

if not defined JavaTemp (
    >&2 echo JavaTemp undefined
    exit /b 2
)

for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%A in (
    '2^>nul reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\%Arg1%\%JavaTemp%" /v JavaHome'
) do if /i "%%~A" == "JavaHome" set "JAVA_HOME=%%~C"

if not defined JAVA_HOME (
    >&2 echo JAVA_HOME undefined
    exit /b 3
) else echo %JAVA_HOME%

exit /b 0
```

Excerpt from `for /?`:

> If the last character in the tokens= string is an
>   asterisk, then an additional variable is
>   allocated and receives the *remaining text* on
>   the line after the last token parsed.

Token options `1,2*`:

- `1` gets the word representing the registry value i.e. `%%A` == `JavaHome`.
- `2` gets the word representing the registry type i.e. `%%B` == `REG_SZ`.
- `*` gets the *remaining text* i.e. `%%C` == `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_06`

No `skip` option used as the link from [Real's HowTo](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0642.html) in the question
shows an integer variation with WinXP and Win7.
A check of the 1st token value decides the line to use which may be
common to WinXP, Win7 and later.

A nested `for` loop is not needed for this task.

Comment: Ah, so then doesn't my original code actually already work? (Thanks for the answer!)

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use the `Reg Query` `/S` option to recursively query all subkeys and values, then include the `/V` option to return data only matching the specifc value name:

Example:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "_K=HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft"
Set "_V=JavaHome"
Set "_D="
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In (
    '"Reg Query "%_K%" /S /V "%_V%" 2>Nul|Find "REG_""') Do Set "_D=%%~B"
If Defined _D Echo %_D% & Pause
```

*You can replace `_D` with `JAVA_HOME` as required*